# Oversampling/Undersampling in respect to Train and Test - Isolation Forest

Tags: unbalanced-classes, anomaly-detection, train, false-positive-rate, isolation-forest

I've got a quite imbalanced data set.

> 144.496 : 162  -> ratio of 1000:1

I would like to use IsolationForest to detect the 162 anomalys.
I've already split the data.

However, the iForest doesn't work well with this ratio (contamination = 0.0015).

Thus, I also tried undersampling (SMOTE) on the train set by chosing a ratio of 1:1, whereas I changed the contamination to 0.5 .. as consequence, the False Positives are very high..

Therefore, I would like to know, how do I have to deal with the ratios in respect Train / Test?
Previously my idea was to balance the data before training, but I have to specify the "contamination" value for the iForest, which is why the test results are catastrophic.

**Could anybody provide me with ideas to tackle this issue?**

[Idea: Use Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hcxi.png)

[image: ConfusionMatrix of SMOTE]]

Comment: Have you looked at the anomalous data? Can you see the difference to normal data?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the anomalous data from the training set and using 0% contamination. Would then use anomalies only for val/test sets